# swiftUI Mapkit and Corelocation causing problems

Tags: swiftui, mapkit, core-location

I'm reposting my question of yesterday and now adding a clean code example to demonstrate the problem
I have a MyCustomMapView, embedding a MKMApView and it starts at a fixed location. I have a function called gotoCoordinate, which accepts a coordinate and then navigates the mapview's center to that coordinate.
In the sample code that can be simulated by clicking on the red button labelleing "Click here to change map position".
This all works great. Until....

in the app I'm working on I also need to have a user location so I have a LocationViewModel handling the request. Once you have given request to access your location, click the button no longer moves the center of the map to that new coordinate.
Once you comment the @StateObject var locationViewModel = LocationViewModel() it is working again.

So it seems that once you are using a location manager with a delegate the map no longer moves when changing it's region

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var locationViewModel = LocationViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        switch locationViewModel.authorizationStatus {
        case .notDetermined:
            AnyView(RequestLocationView())
                .environmentObject(locationViewModel)
        case .restricted:
            ErrorView(errorText: "Location use is restricted.")
        case .denied:
            ErrorView(errorText: "The app does not have location permissions. Please enable them in settings.")
        default:
            EmptyView()
        }
        
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            
            DisplayMapView(size:geometry.size)
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation
import MapKit

struct MyCustomMapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var map =  MKMapView()   // << constructor contract !!
    let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:31,longitude: -86 )
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        map.delegate = context.coordinator
        map.showsUserLocation = true
        map.showsCompass = true
 
        let region  = MKCoordinateRegion(
            center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coordinate.latitude,longitude: coordinate.longitude),
            span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1))
        map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        return map
    }
    
    func gotoCoordinate(_ newCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D ){
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: newCoordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.2, longitudeDelta: 0.2))
        map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }
      
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: Context) {
        
    }
    
     
    func makeCoordinator() -> MyCustomMapView.Coordinator {
        return MyCustomMapView.Coordinator(parent1: self)
    }
    
    final class Coordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
        var parent:MyCustomMapView
        init(parent1:MyCustomMapView){
            parent = parent1
        }
    }//class Coordinator
    
    
}
```

```swift
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation
import MapKit
struct DisplayMapView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    var size: CGSize

    var startCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:40.741895,longitude: -73.989308)
    
    var map = MyCustomMapView()
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment:.top){
            map
             
            VStack(alignment:.leading){
                HStack {
         
                        HStack {
                            Text("Click here to change map position")
                                .onTapGesture(){
                                    map.gotoCoordinate(startCoordinate)
                                }
                            
                             
                        }
                        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 8, leading: 6, bottom: 8, trailing: 6))
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .background(Color(.red))
                        .cornerRadius(10.0)
                 
                }
            }.padding(.top,50).padding(.leading,20).padding(.trailing,20)
        }.ignoresSafeArea()

    }
}
```

```swift
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation

class LocationViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    @Published var authorizationStatus: CLAuthorizationStatus
    @Published var lastSeenLocation: CLLocation?
    @Published var currentPlacemark: CLPlacemark?
    
    private let locationManager: CLLocationManager
    static let shared = LocationViewModel()
    
    override init() {
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        authorizationStatus = locationManager.authorizationStatus
        
        super.init()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.distanceFilter = 0.4
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    
    func requestPermission() {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
    
    func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
        authorizationStatus = manager.authorizationStatus
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        lastSeenLocation = locations.first
    }
    
    
}

struct RequestLocationView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var locationViewModel: LocationViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing:50) {
            Image(systemName: "location.circle")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
                .foregroundColor(Color.init(red: 0.258, green: 0.442, blue: 0.254))
            Button(action: {
                locationViewModel.requestPermission()
            }, label: {
                Label(LocalizedStringKey("allowLocationAccess"), systemImage: "location")
            })
            .padding(10)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .background(.green)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8))
            Text("We need your permission to give you the best experience.")
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                .font(.caption)
        }
    }
}

struct ErrorView: View {
    var errorText: String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "xmark.octagon")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
            Text(errorText)
        }
        .padding()
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .background(Color.red)
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare your coordinates as a stateful variable, either as `@State` or as `@Published` within an observable object:

```
struct DisplayMapView: View {
  @State var coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:40.741895,longitude: -73.989308)
```

Then pass the coordinates in as an argument to your view - no need to store your view as a variable:

```
ZStack(alignment: .top) {
  MyMapView(coordinates: coordinates)
  VStack(alignment: .leading) {
    // etc.
```

Then you’ll need to do some rejigging in your `UIViewRepresentable`. You mustn't retain `map` as a separate instance outside `makeUIView` and `updateUIView` - SwiftUI structs can be recreated at will, so that would release your MKMapView instance and create a new one. Instead, the object returned by `makeUIView` is retained for you by the system. You do need to declare a variable that will accept the coordinates argument above, and then respond to any changes in it in `updateUIView`.

```
struct MyMapView: UIViewRepresentable {
  var coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D

  func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
    let map = MKMapView()
    map.delegate = context.coordinator
    // etc.
    return map
  }

  func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: Coordinator) {
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinates, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.2, longitudeDelta: 0.2))
    uiView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
  }
}
```

Now, when the user taps, instead of calling a function inside your view, you update the `DisplayMapView`’s `coordinates` variable and the `UIViewRepresentable`’s update logic should redraw the map in the correct position.

Comment: I've tried it but doesn't work also I need to have the reference since I have other functions to be called on the MyCustomMapView

Comment: You shouldn't call functions on a child view, ever! Instead you keep the state you need at a higher level, and allow the view to respond to changes in that data. If your view itself needs to make changes to data that’s owned by something higher up in the hierarchy, you should use bindings, pass in an `@ObservableObject` that’s owned by something higher up, or use an environment object.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need to have the ability to use a button to move the map to a certain location and also to set the region to the result of a local search. How would you change the code to support that, not hacing the functions in the child

Comment: In that case I’d have a `MKCoordinateRegion` state variable outside the map. You could then have a method at that level that changes the region’s centre, and another which allows you to set the region to a completely different location. Your view should then respond to those changes as described above.

Comment: Scott, got it reworked to as you proposed. now when sending a new region to the ObserverObject the map navigates to it which is great. However since it is a binding when i move the map around or zoom in, it always returns to the selectedRegion from the observeredObject

Comment: As you've made the `context.coordinator` the MKMapView's delegate, you can declare any `MKMapViewDelegate` methods ([listed here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapviewdelegate)) in your `Coordinator` class. There are three methods related to the map view's visible region changing - each passes in the `MKMapView` instance, so you can get that instance's `.region` property and use it to update the observed object's region  - e.g. `parent1.observedObject.selectedRegion = mapView.region`